# activiti taskService complete fails when executed concurrently

Tags: alfresco, activiti

Hi I am facing a strange situation where I am trying to set a set of tasks as complete all concurrently.

The first one goes through and second one goes through sometimes (rarely) but mostly doesnt go through.
When I do these individually they work.
Something to do with database locking I feel. Is there some workaround or code for executing task and variable updates concurrently ?

Answer (score 0):

Do they belong to the same process instance?
And yes, there will be a db locking mechanism in place, because when you complete each task a process instance will need to move forward. 
Can you please clarify what are you trying to solve? what is your business scenario?

Cheers

Comment: Yes, same process instance. There are two parallel user tasks.. but the user can choose to complete those simultaneously through a client program which call the respective apis to complete these two parallel tasks. Is there a way out for this?

Comment: You will need to retry if the call fails, that is to keep the data consistent. That's from the client point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Activiti uses pre-emptive locking and this can cause problems for parallel tasks.
Typically if you use the "exclusive" flag the problems go away (https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#exclusiveJobs).

Keep in mind that jobs never actually run in parallel, the job engine selects jobs to run and if there are multiple they will be run sequentially (which appears to be parallel to the user).

Comment: The documentation says that exclusive flag is by default True. If that is the case, why is this problem occurring ( only one of the two tasks getting completed) ?